# Terms of Service and Adversarially Interoperable Apps

Tags: contract-law, terms-of-service, digital-contract, adhesion-contracts

Applications like [NewPipe](https://newpipe.net/) and [Geddit](https://github.com/kaangiray26/geddit-app) seem to be becoming more popular. These applications are "adversarially interoperable": they work with and can display content from large services such as YouTube and Reddit, but the services have not given them any sort of official permission to do so. (Usually the authors look at how the web site works and just do what it does, or what someone else described it as doing.)

Usually, these applications do not give their user notice of any contract offers from the services they interact with. The applications don't work by displaying web pages, and contract offers like terms of service are usually provided as part of a web page, instead of e.g. in video form at the beginning of a YouTube video.

If a person first starts using a service through this kind of third-party application, are they likely to be taken by a court as having agreed to the service's terms of service contract, despite not having notice of its terms?